# How to get a list of checked boxes in grails

Tags: list, grails, checkbox, groovy

In grails, I am trying to get a list of checked check boxes.
I have the list of check boxes, but my issues are two:

1) when I click on a single item in the list and click submit - I only get the value "on". If I click more than one check box item, I get something like this:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@5a37f9f7
```

2). I do not get a list or the name of the item checked.

Here is my code for the check boxes in the gsp:

```
<g:form action="submitForm">
    <ul class="columns3">
        <g:each in="${name}" var="fileName" >
            <g:checkBox value="${false}" name="${ 'fileName'}" /> ${fileName.replaceFirst(~/\.[^\.]+$/, '')}<br>
        </g:each> 
    </ul>
    <br>
    <br>
    <g:submitButton name="Submit"/>
</g:form>
```

and here is the controller code (groovy):

```
class Read_dirController {

    def index() { 

        def list = []

        def dir = new File("/home/ironmantis/Documents/business/test_files")
        dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
          list << file
        }

        list.each {
            println it.name.replaceFirst(~/\.[^\.]+$/, '')
          }

        render(view: "index",  model: [name:list.name])

        params.list('fileName')

    }

        def displayForm() { }

        def submitForm(String fileName) {
            render fileName
            //render(view: "tests_checked", fileName)
        }
}
```

I tried to bind an id to the check boxes, but I keep getting an exception error.

Any help you can give I truly appreciate it; I am new to grails.

ironmantis7x

Comment: update: I added render params.list('fileName') to the controller and it now lists all the check boxes checked - but only the state. I still need the actual names.

Comment: When clicking on multiple checkboxes you are getting an array of values. So you should not use String type variable for auto data binding. And to know what all parameters you are receiving from request you can check with `param.keySet()` inside controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way,

```
def submitForm() { 
def values = request.getParameterValues("fileName") 
//here values contains string array which are selected in checkbox
}
```

Comment: I guess instead of name="${ 'fileName'}" u need to use name="fileName"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the beautiful command object for this. For this ,first make a class RequestCO having the boolean fields.

```
class RequestCO {
  boolean isChecked;
  String name;
}
```

And

```
class RequestParentCO {
List<RequestCO> requestCOs = [].withLazyDefault { new RequestCO() }
}
```

Now you just simply bind all your request to RequestParentCO in your action:

```
def submitForm(RequestParentCO parentCO) {
    println parentCO.requestCOs.findAll { it.isChecked }
}
```

This will give you all the checked checkboxes results.

**GSP**

```
<g:form action="process">
<ul class="columns3">
    <g:each in="${["one", "two", "three"]}" var="fileName" status="i">
        <g:hiddenField name="requestCOs[${i}].name" value="${fileName}"/>
        <g:checkBox name="requestCOs[${i}].isChecked"/> ${fileName}<br>
    </g:each>
</ul>
<g:submitButton name="Submit"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use request.getParameterValues("fileName") method, this will give selected checkbox in string array

Comment: is that to be used in the controller or the view (gsp)?

Comment: used in controller

Comment: hmmm ... I tried that and it did not return any values.
my syntax was: render request.getParameterValues("fileName").
was that correct (it compiled and ran with no compilation error - but the result was an error.